# difficult insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, luhn

I am using mysql/php.

my table looks like

```
id (int autoincrement)  
voucher(varchar 25)
```

I am generating voucher codes where the code is:

- 1 random number (eg 64)
- 1 fixed number   (eg 352)
- value of id field (1,2,3,4,5...)
- 1 checkdigit (luhn algorithm).

The obvious issue in doing this with php is that I have to do a select, get the next autoincrement value, calculate the code, insert, by which time another row could have been inserted.

What I want to do is instead,

do `insert into vouchers (voucher) value('64352')` and have it generate the rest of me.

How can I do this? function/trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using InnoDB, an easy fix would just be to use your existing code and wrap it in a MySQL transaction. i.e. in pseudocode:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

# get next autoincrement value into: $next

# do your INSERT query

# get the actual last inserted ID into: $actual

if ($next === $actual) {
  mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {
  mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
  # and raise an Exception or return an error
}
```

**EDIT/ADD:**

Since you mentioned triggers, I looked into that and believe it's doable. A couple of issues.

1. Accessing the "next autoincrement ID" from the trigger ... I don't know a "good" way to do this. In INSERT queries you have access only to NEW and not OLD (existing rows) values (see [Trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)). What I'm doing to do in the example is just maintain a separate counter @vcount on the server. To initialize this value to whatever the ID currently is, you would just do "SET @vcount = 42;"
2. Luhn algorithm. You will have to implement this as a SQL function. [Here's](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=68) a Luhn validator in SQL you could crib from. Alternately you could hash/checksum with a native MySQL function like MD5 (and use only the first X chars if you need a short voucher code). In any case you need to make a hash function ... I'll just use "Luhn" below.

Anyway here's what the trigger would look like:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER make_voucher_code BEFORE INSERT ON vouchers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @vcount = @vcount + 1;
    SET NEW.voucher = CONCAT(
        NEW.voucher, 
        CAST(@vcount AS CHAR),
        Luhn(CONCAT(NEW.voucher, CAST(@vcount AS CHAR))));
END;
//
delimeter ;
```

Then, in your INSERTs, you would put just '64352' in the query, as you've suggested. The trigger would append the rest.

Personally, unless you or someone else can solve the autoincrement/@vcount problem better, I would still prefer doing the MySQL transaction, which will do a better job than this of keeping everything atomic and keeping all your app code in PHP.

Comment: I've been looking at MySQL triggers and I believe it's doable. I'll update my answer with some half-baked example code. Or, you could possibly still do the transaction via code igniter. Embedding app code into triggers/stored procedures has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: OK, my trigger ended up more fully baked than I expected. Add a Luhn function and it should work. In my example Luhn() is returning the checksum value as a string, so if you have it return an int you'll just need to wrap the return value in CAST( AS CHAR). Good luck!

Comment: A third option ... you could add the Luhn function, then instead of a trigger do the whole thing as an [INSERT with nested SELECTs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html). That may be the way to go, but not sure how Code Igniter-friendly it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or do the insert with value 0, then get the insert id, compute the value and update the record at .